# Can you miss packets, when socket is currently not receiving?

Tags: linux, networking, udp, icmp, raw-sockets

I got sockets that are listening to `ICMP/UDP` packets. If the socket receives a packet and the handling of this packet takes too long (code after `socket.receive()`), could following packets be missed, since I'm currently not at `socket.receive()` part?

Comment: Yes. Trivially, when the UDP buffer fills up and the stack drops packets. The amount of loss depends on buffer size and required depth (to not lose packets). Windows and Linux allow this setting to be configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, yes. The implementation is free to discard packets any place it wishes to. However, it would be a pretty poor implementation if it didn't provide some reasonable amount of buffering, and Linux does.